# can't convert Enumerator into Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, enumerator

While working on one application I am getting this error:

> can't convert Enumerator into Array

Here is my code, `mr_collection` is MongoID query.

```
mr_collection = self.where(query).map_reduce(map, reduce).finalize(finalize).out({:replace => 'mr_results'})
paginator = WillPaginate::Collection.new(page, limit, collection_count)

collection = mr_collection.find(
   :sort => sort,
   :limit => limit,
   :skip => skip
)
paginator.replace(collection)
```

While getting `mr_collection`, if I inspect the result `mr_collection` gives me:

```
[   
   {"_id"=>1.0, "value"=>{"s"=>4.2, "p"=>14.95, "pml"=>0.01993}}, 
   {"_id"=>2.0, "value"=>{"s"=>3.7, "p"=>12.9, "pml"=>0.0172}}, 
   {"_id"=>3.0, "value"=>{"s"=>4.2, "p"=>12.9, "pml"=>0.0172}}, 
   {"_id"=>4.0, "value"=>{"s"=>4.0, "p"=>11.95, "pml"=>0.01593}}, 
   {"_id"=>300.0, "value"=>{"s"=>0.0, "p"=>8.95, "pml"=>0.01193}}, 
]
```

While getting `collection`, if I inspect the result `collection` gives me:

```
#<Enumerator: []:find({:sort=>[["value.s", :desc], ["value.pml", :asc]], :limit=>10, :skip=>0})>
```

I am getting error on the line `paginator.replace(collection)`. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 & Rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collection` is an `Enumerator` which obviously can't convert into an `Array`, which is what `replace` expects.

Here are the comments from the rubydocs:

> **Enumerable#find(ifnone = nil) { |e| ... }**
>
> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block
> is not false. If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its
> result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.
>
> **If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.**

Therefore you have two options:

1. If you want all elements, yield from the Enumerator to an Array.
2. If you only want the first match, supply a block that determines what the match is.

Hope this helps.

(Moral of the story: always read the docs!)

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea about mongoid having never used it.
But a search has brought to fore an awfully similar question -
[Mongoid 3 - access map_reduce results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784727/mongoid-3-access-map-reduce-results)

Unfortunately my environent is not set to test the magic of

```
collection = mr_collection.send(:documents).sort(sort).limit(limit).skip(skip).to_a
```

Have you had a look at this link? Hopefully it'll help solve your issue!